# Calculate the profit from different tables in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i have two tables, Tbought and Tsold
Tbought contains items i bought

```
  ID   |ItemName| PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfItems I bought |DateIBought| 
  1    |  tea   |       3      |            6           |15/11/2015 |
  2    | coffee |       5      |            4           |16/11/2015 |
  3    |  tea   |       3      |            10          |20/12/2015 |
  4    | juice  |       5      |            15          | 1/1/2016  |
  5    | coffee |       5      |            5           | 15/3/2016 |
  6    | water  |       5      |            2           | 16/4/2016 |
```

And Tsold contains items i sold

```
  ID   |ItemName| PriceOfUnit  | NumberOfItems I sold   |total sold $|  PriceWhenBought| 
  1    | coffee |       7      |            6           |     30     |         5       |
  2    |  tea   |       5      |            9           |     45     |         3       |
  3    | coffee |       7      |            2           |     8      |         5       |
  5    | juice  |       6      |            11          |     55     |         5       |
```

if i bought coffee and price of unit was 5 that's in Tbought
 now i sold coffee for 7 so `my profit = 7 - 5 = 2`
I need to calculate profit , so i thought i can get price of unit from Tbought -without entring it again in Tsold - and calculate my profit in Tsold table as above
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do this by creating a query that joins both tables on `ItemName`, then you can calculate a field like `Profit: Tsold.PriceOfUnit - Tbought.PriceOfUnit`.

But there is a problem: "coffee" appears multiple times in `Tbought`. How can your query know which `Tbought.PriceOfUnit` to use if they are different?

**EDIT**

Then you first need a query to calculate the arithmetic mean per Item, it would look like this:

```
SELECT ItemName, Sum([PriceOfUnit]) / Count(*) AS AvgPriceBought
FROM Tbought
GROUP BY ItemName
```

Then join Tsold with this query on ItemName, and add a query field like this:

```
Profit: Tsold.PriceOfUnit - QAvgBought.AvgPriceBought
```

Comment: i need to calculate arithmetic mean if there are items appear multiple time like coffee
if i had coffee = 3 , coffee = 4 and coffee = 6
i need profit = coffee when sold -(3+4+6)/3